# CSS one element reverting on page change

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this weird css bug. It almost seems like a caching issue or something with chrome as I can't replicate locally.

I send the user an invite and if they go to the invite page and then return to any other page that shows the banner, it's displayed wrong as one line of text is in times new roman.

The bug only happens if you've not been to the site before and you go to invite page then click back to any other page that has the banner.

2 things I've noted that are really unusual and I'm struggling to understand are:

- The text that is displaying incorrectly is one word in an `<a>`
  element, but parts of the text are fine.
- When I open inspector and toggle any part of the css for the element.
  It resets to how it should look immediately.

Here are some pictures:

**How the banner looks**
[image]

**How it usually/should look**
[image]

**The `<a>` tag containing the button**
[image]

As a sidenote I'm using chrome and rails 4 without turbolinks. Here is the code for the button:

```
.childminder-banner .btn {
    padding: 3px 1em;
}

.btn-blue {
    background: #34A9CD;
    color: white;
}

.btn {
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: none .1s ease-out 0s;
    transition: none .1s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition-property: color,background,border;
    transition-property: color,background,border;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: "Gordita";
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .1s ease-out,background-color .1s ease-out,color .1s ease-out;
    transition: border-color .1s ease-out,background-color .1s ease-out,color .1s ease-out;
    background-color: #FF8027;
    border-color: #FF8027;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give style to the anchor tag `display:inline-block`

```
a{
   display:inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: It already has that attribute set. I've added the full code for the button in the question now.